# 警告「xxxに代入した値は使われていない」の対処方法

Tags: c

```
環境: CやC++の開発環境
```

コンパイル時の警告についての質問です。

以下のテスト用関数を用意したとします。ステップ実行でvalの値をチェックするためです。

```
void Test_someFunc() {
    int val;
    val = getVal();
}
```

上記コードを含めたソースをコンパイルすると以下の警告が出ます (確認環境: C++ Buiilder XE4)。

> valに代入した値は使われていない

この警告自体は未使用の変数がわかって便利なのですが、上記のようなテスト関数でも警告が出てしまいます。

こういう場合、どのようにして警告を表示しないようにできるでしょうか（警告をOFFにしない方法で)。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 次の行に`(void)val;`を書く、を試してみて下さい。 あるいは、`(void)(val = getVal());`

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確かに警告が消えました。

両者の振舞としては何をするのでしょうか? valという値のポインタの先の処理をする？などちょっとわかりません。

Comment: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writing_warning-free_code
の
Unused parameters
に記載がありますね。

Comment: 式の結果に対して`(void)`を指定するとコンパイラにこの式の結果は使わない(例えば`printf`の結果のような返値が使用されない時など)ことをコンパイラに伝えることができます。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

式の結果に対して(void)を指定するとコンパイラにこの式の結果は使わない(例えばprintfの結果のような返値が使用されない時など明示的に値を破棄する)ことをコンパイラに‌​伝えることができます。

参考：[6.8.3 Expression and null statements](http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/resources/c11standard.pdf)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。資料もありがとうございます。
勉強になりました。
資料を読んでさらに良いコードが作れるようになりたいと思います。

Answer (score 7):

> ステップ実行でvalの値をチェックするためです。

一例に対しての反論では意味をなさないかもしれませんが、

```
assert(val != 0);
```

など確実に成立すべき条件を記載すれば、コンパイラーも警告しませんしテストにもなります。

Comment: 確かにもっとassert()を使うべきなのかもしれません。一方で、valの値をチェックしたい場合としては「valが有効範囲に入っているか」以外にも「valの計算結果を知りたい」という場面もあります。中間変数の値を知ることで検算を行う、というデバッグを想定しています。

Comment: @sevenOfNine デバッグをするなという指摘ではありません。何かしら１つ式を書けば警告されなくなるので、`(void)val`よりも有用な式を書いてはどうですか？ という提案です。

Comment: @sayuriさん
なるほど。
`(void)val;`の行の代わりに`assert(val != 0);`はどうですか、という意味なのですね。
それは確かに有用に思います。

Comment: @sayuriさん `(void)val;`では組込みのIDEで警告が出ました。`assert(val != 0);`だと同じ環境では警告が出ませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: と思っていましたら、assert()を使うことで組込み側でシンボル"_write"が見つからないというビルドエラーになりました。難しいですね。

Answer (score 2):

以下のような、使用しない変数を引数にしたダミー関数を呼び出す方法はいかがでしょうか。

Cの場合:

```
// 共通ヘッダあたりに定義
static inline void unused_impl(int dummy, ...) {}
#define UNUSED(...) unused_impl(0, __VA_ARGS__)
(中略)
    // 関数内
    int val1 = f();
    int val2 = g();
    UNUSED(val1, val2)
```

C++の場合:

```
// 共通ヘッダあたりに定義
template<typename... TS> void unused(const TS &...) {}
(中略)
    // 関数内
    int val1 = f();
    int val2 = g();
    unused(val1, val2);
```

長所:

- マクロ/関数名を適切なものにすることで、「使用しない」という意思が伝わりやすくなる。
- 複数の変数を同時に指定できる。

短所:

- それぞれC99、C++11以降に対応している必要がある。(C++ Builder XE4 は対応してましたっけ？ 新しめのは対応しているようですが)
- 最適化をかけないと、ダミー関数呼び出しのオーバーヘッドがかかる。

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々な方法がありますね。
XE4はC++11の対応は32bit版、64bit版で異なりますね。C++11機能の使用は将来のバージョンで検討することになりそうです。

Comment: 複数同時指定に拘らなければ、C++03でも使えます、とだけ返そうとしましたが、指定する手間が `(void)` でキャストするのと変わらなくなりますね。 意思の明示も、`#define UNUSED(x) (void)x` で十分そう。

Comment: コードの意図を残す、という点からdefineなども有用ですね。ありがとうございます。